# DB query in for loop errors on second loop (PHP, Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops

A simple loop loops through an array and deletes database records...

Controller:

```
foreach ($deletedTags as $deletedTag) {
    $tagId = $this->tags_model->get_tag_id($deletedTag);
    $this->tags_model->delete_tag_association_by_tag($workId, $tagId);  
}
```

`$deletedTags` is an array, an example being:

```
Array ( [0] => purple [1] => trees [2] => green )
```

Model:

```
function get_tag_id($tag) {
    $this->db->where('tags.name', $tag);
    $query = $this->db->get(self::TABLE);
    return $query->row()->id;
}
```

When there is only one value in `$deletedTags` it works fine. When there's more than one value the model function `get_tag_id($tag)` breaks on the second loop. It errors on the line `return $query->row()->id;` with:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$id
```

Any idea why?

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer your question fully without knowing what $deletedTags is - is it a single or multidimensional array or is it an object?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. For some reason it's erroring because it can only find the first tag in the array in the db (even though the other tags do exist in the db). I added a tag_exists check and all is fine...

```
foreach ($deletedTags as $deletedTag) {
    if ($this->tags_model->tag_exists($deletedTag)) {
        $tagId = $this->tags_model->get_tag_id($deletedTag);
        $this->tags_model->delete_tag_association_by_tag($workId, $tagId);
    }
}
```

Weird.